# LINQ Query with clause tied to a Column

Tags: c#, linq, bitwise-and

I encountered this LINQ statement, which after some exhaustive Googling, I haven't found a comprehensive explanation:

```
var x = Context.TableName
               .AsNoTracking()
               .Where(x => (x.ColumnName & 2) == 2)
               .Select(x => new {col = x.Column})
               .ToList();
```

The part that I don't completely get is the `.Where` clause here.

```
.Where(x => (x.ColumnName & 2) == 2)
```

I am unsure whether that value resolves to an `'AND'` clause?

Additional info:
Found out that the & means the Bitwise AND operator. But how is it being applied to the value in place? For example, if the Column value is 514, it is being retrieved, but if it is 512, it is not being retrieved. I just want to understand how the bitwise is checking its applicability in the said values (514, 512).

Edit: Typo on 3 on the bitwise. Should be 2!

Comment: What's the type of `ColumnName` ?

Comment: that's bitwise AND ... fyi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `ColumnName` is of an integer or of some other whole number type, then `(x.ColumnName & 2)` will do bitwise AND. Since 2 is `0000 0000 0010` in binary calculus, expression `(x.ColumnName & 2) == 2` means that the value of `x.ColumnName` must match pattern `**** **** ***1*` in binary calculus.

For example, if the value of x.ColumnName is 514, then the result of `(x.ColumnName & 2)` will be

```
0010 0000 0010 (514)
&
0000 0000 0010 (2)
= 
0000 0000 0010 (2)
```

and the expression `(x.ColumnName & 2) == 2` will return `true`.

If the value of x.ColumnName is 512, then the result of `(x.ColumnName & 2)` will be

```
0010 0000 0000 (512)
&
0000 0000 0010 (2)
= 
0000 0000 0000 (0)
```

and the expression `(x.ColumnName & 2) == 2` will return `false`.

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This approach lets you test if the second least significant bit of the binary representation of `x.ColumnName` is set:

- `val & 2` masks off the bits other than second least significant
- Comparison to `2` checks that bit is set to `1`.

This translates to RDBMS-dependent bitwise `AND` operator (operator `&` in SQL Server).

Comment: I did a typo on the value for the bitwise, can you please explain again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this table

[image]

When `X` and `Y` are true only then `X&Y` is true. Otherwise, it's false.
Number 2 in binary is `10`. So, `X&2` will always return 2 *(in binary `10`)* or 0
For example:

**15 & 2 = 2**

```
1111 (15)
&
0010 (2)
= 
0010 (2)
```

**13 & 2 = 0**

```
1101 (13)
&
0010 (2)
= 
0000 (0)
```

[This](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/bit-manipulation/) article is really helpful